# Find 25 using 6, 25, 9, 8 only

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

You can only use these numbers once, so not square root or cubed root or anything else.

Good Luck!!

Comment: What other rules are there besides no square root, or cubed root? Can we only use basic + - / * ?

Comment: Anything. It could even be sine or cosine

Comment: You can only use the numbers once, so because there is no 2 or 3 you can't do square or cubes, but you can use any other operation.

Comment: Found it. It's the second number in the list.

Comment: To eliminate Ian's solution: does each of the four numbers have to be used exactly once?

Comment: Yes they do....

Answer (score 4):

> $25 * (9-8)^6$ ...........................

Answer (score 2):

> $25\times\lfloor\log(8+6-9)\rfloor$

or

> $25+\lfloor\log\log(8+6-9)\rfloor$

Comment: Also `25 | (9 & 8 & 6)`.

Answer (score 1):

> $25^{\left \lfloor log_{9}{6*8}  \right \rfloor}$

.

> $25^{\left \lfloor log_{8}{6*9}  \right \rfloor}$

.

> $25^{\left \lfloor log_{6}{\binom{9}{8}}  \right \rfloor}$

.

### :)

> $ \left | 25, \Phi, ,\left \{  \Phi \right \}, \left \{   \left \{  \Phi \right \} \right \}, \cdots \right | + \left | 6, \Phi, ,\left \{  \Phi \right \}, \left \{   \left \{  \Phi \right \} \right \}, \cdots \right | + \left | 8, \Phi, ,\left \{  \Phi \right \}, \left \{   \left \{  \Phi \right \} \right \}, \cdots \right | + \left | 9, \Phi, ,\left \{  \Phi \right \}, \left \{   \left \{  \Phi \right \} \right \}, \cdots \right |  $

Comment: How did you get that answer?

Comment: @SamuelMartin: A better question is how can anybody not get the answer.

Comment: @Name that's not really an explanation, Samuel is just asking how you thought of this

Comment: IMO once you say "Ah, I'll allow sine and cosine", the whole world of mathematical functions can be thrown at the numbers and nothing can stop you anymore.

Comment: @Name can you please explain what's going on in your fourth solution?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is to do this which is shown below

> 25%(6*8*9)

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: mod means remainder when divided by, the remainder when 25 is divided by 432 is 25

Comment: I think % is only denoted as mod in computer science?

Comment: Yeah, But I believe its still fine as you still get the ans.